# зачем нужен state в AbstractQueuedSynchronizer

Tags: java

AbstractQueuedSynchronizer содержит внутреннее поле state. 0 и 1 зарезервированы для состояния - блокировки нет, и блокировка установлена. Зачем пользователю свой state заводить ? Например, в методе tryAcquire(int) или tryRelease(int).

PS а так же объясните в чем отличие tryRelease(int) и tryReleaseShared(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет никакого резервирования значений 0 и 1 для поля `state`. Т.к. `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` является абстракным вспомогательным классом для реализации собственных примитивов синхронизации, вы вольны изменять значение поля `state` как вам заблагорассудится через методы `setState` и `compareAndSetState` (конечно же в пределах области допустимых значений для типа `int`).

Например `ReentrantLock` использует поле `state` для хранения количества захватов блокировки потоком-владельцем, т.к. в случае reentrancy мы не можем просто освободить блокировку по первому вызову `unlock` в силу симметричности контракта для методов `lock` и `unlock`.

Блокировка может быть получена в эксклюзивное пользование (exclusive) и в неэксклюзивное (non-exclusive или shared), и для работы с такими блокировками используются пары методов `tryAcquire/tryRelease` и `tryAcquireShared/tryReleaseShared` соответственно. Спецификации этих методов различаются, и в случае с эксклюзивной блокировкой возвращается булево значение (нам достаточно знать смогли мы получить/освободить блокировку или нет), тогда как в случае неэксклюзивной - целочисленное значение (если мы смогли получить блокировку, то нам нужно знать, можем ли мы взять ее еще раз в этом же режиме или нет).

Пример использования `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` с получением блокировки в неэксклюзивном режиме - это реализация `CountDownLatch`. Более сложный пример, когда блокировка может использоваться как в эксклюзивном, так и в неэксклюзивном режимах - это реализация `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.

Comment: спасибо за отличнейший ответ!